# How to unpad a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
m = [0 65 34 0; 0 55 8 19; 89 0 0 10]
m_padded = padarray(m,[4,4],0,'both')
```

I just have `m_padded`, and I'm trying to find a function that creates `m`? I thought of finding the indexes with `find` and add zeros to the borders, but how can I do that efficiently?

Comment: `unpadded_m = m_padded(4+1:end-4, 4+1:end-4)`?

Comment: or probably this: `[r,c]=find(m_padded);` 
`unpadded_m=m_padded(min(r):end-min(r)+1, min(c):end-min(c)+1);` ?

Comment: @Sardar Usama: Thanks it works great! Could you post it as an answer please so that I can accept it?

Comment: I added an alternate generic answer which is applicable for any padding size and direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to extract row and column subscripts of `m` in `m_padded`. Now use [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) and [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) to find the starting and ending subscripts respectively of rows and columns of `m` in `m_padded`.  Use these subscripts to generate indices to extract `m`.

```
[r, c] = find(m_padded); 
unpadded_m = m_padded(min(r):max(r), min(c):max(c));
```

The above code is applicable for padding done with any size and in any direction; be it `pre`, `post`, or `both`.